# Comparing pre-test post-test results t-test normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, t-test, pre-post-comparison

Is the best way to compare the intervention group (n=32) with the control group (n=32) to do a t-test? I've got pre-test and post-test results and did t-test of both the pre-scores (IG compared to CG) and then later the post-scores (IG compared to CG). Do I need to investigate normal distribution by a bell chart although I'm just investigating a small group that is selected out of convenience?

Should I have done an ANOVA instead?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Please provide more information about your data & hypothesis. For example: What is the outcome variable? What do you mean by "selected out of convenience"? Do you only have pre- and post-scores or you have other (potentially) relevant measurements?

Comment: Linear mixed models could be a possible solution. [Here](https://thestatsgeek.com/2020/12/30/mixed-model-repeated-measures-mmrm-in-stata-sas-and-r/#:~:text=Linear%20mixed%20models%20are%20a,and%2For%20correlated%20residual%20errors.) is an example of lmm with STATA, SAS, and R. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If I am correct, you have a control study that has a control group where something was measured, then a treatment happened, and something was measured again.  If so, than the example data set below can be a step-by-step guide to help you know if the t-test is the right test?? And what are a few of the different ways of knowing how to do this.

Since you did not provide any data, I made one up in R.

Let's pretend if I want to know if coffee consumption increases alertness of professors teaching a statistics class. There will be a measurement before coffee consumption, and their alertness is measured on a scale of 0-200, where 200 = **really** alert.  Then, **the same person** drinks coffee, and their alertness is then rated again. I do all of this for 32 different professors (N=32 professors, N=64 total measurements (each one measured twice, don't forget)

Here's a pretend dataset

```
# Create an empty data frame with column names
example_df <- data.frame( "ID" = character(0), "alertness" = integer(0))
```

```
#Assign names to x 
variable_names <- c("control", "after_intervention")
```

```
# Assign names to y
w<-rnorm(32, mean=10, sd=2)
x<-rnorm(32, mean=8, sd=2)
```

```
#combine everything to create dataframe (df)
df <- data.frame( "ID" = variable_names, "alertness" = c(w,x))
```

Can I do a t-test? Does my data meet the normality assumptions?

- We can do this by checking quantile-quantile plots with the `qqPlot()` command from the `library(car)`
- We can run a shapiro test to see if we meet normality assumptions
- We can make histograms of our data and make a decision based on the shape.
- **There are other options too**, please ask if interested

**quantile-quantile plots**

```
library(dplyr)

control <- filter(df, ID=="control")
after_intervention <- filter(df, ID=="after_intervention")


library(car)


par(mfrow = c(1,2), cex = .8)

qqPlot(control$alertness, dist = "norm",
       mean = mean(control$alertness), sd = sd(control$alertness),
       xlab = "Theor. quantiles (norm)", ylab = "Empirical quantiles", main = "before")

qqPlot(after_intervention$alertness, dist = "norm",
       mean = mean(after_intervention$alertness), sd = sd(after_intervention$alertness),
       xlab = "Theor. quantiles (norm)", ylab = "Empirical quantiles", main = "after")
```

[image]

The qqPlots actually look pretty good, and it seems the normality assumption is met. But what if I want to do another test to check. Lets do a shapiro test

```
shapiro.test(control$alertness)
shapiro.test(after_intervention$alertness)
```

[image]

The p-value of both tests is not less than .05, which indicates that the data is normally distributed.

Ok, but now I want a third way of knowing, lets do some histograms

```
hist(control$alertness)
hist(after_intervention$alertness)
```

[image]

Also looks fine.

So, here you could do a **paired** t-test, paired because we measured the same subject (same professor). It would be unpaired if this was not done (aka we measured different professors)

To do an anova, you can directly put your data in a linear model

```
model <- lm(alertness~ID, data = df)
summary(model)
```

[image]

And at the bottom, you see the anova summary, with f-statistic, and p-value.

Finally, you can see that the linear model truly did to a proper anova, but just literally running an anova, and seeing that the results match, by running the following code

```
difference <-aov(df$alertness~df$ID)
summary(difference)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: why down vote my answer without an explanation?  All information I provided are studied methods to check distribution

Comment: It's frustrating to get a downvote and no feedback, so here are a couple of suggestions (though it I didn't downvote your answer). To start with, the OP provides very little (insufficient?) information, so you basically come up with your own question. Next time consider whether there is enough substance to the question to warrant an answer.

Comment: You ignore the single piece of information provided: that the sample sizes are 32 for both groups. This matters because you then proceed to check normality and this is easier with a sample of size 200. The coffee/alertness example probably doesn't have anything to do with the OP's actual domain, so if you want to simulate data keep it abstract and call it x and y. Finally, I don't think tests for normality are a great idea but let's call this difference in opinion about statistical practice.

Comment: @dipetkov I agree that they have only 32 data points / treatment.  Nonetheless, the same steps can be applied as I mentioned.  The question is lacking info, I agree, which is why I made up a dataset to help visualize my response, but it's true the OP lacked to provide us with sufficient information to maybe even merit a response.  Finally, the coffee/alertness just shows a setup with a baseline (control) and manipulation (intervention). I just made up names, but tried to respect the authors original question.   I hope this clarifies any/all points.  All the best.

Comment: Using n = 200 instead of n = 32 to do a hypothesis test is not the best illustration because the power of a test increases with sample size.

Comment: @dipetkov the whole answer has been updated with 32 data points for control and 32 for intervention.  All plots and so forth are updated too. Thanks

Comment: Don't use hypothesis tests such as the Shapiro-Wilk test to test assumptions. These tests do not answer the relevant questions and if you base your decision about what analyses to run on them, the performance of those tests is distorted. Also, a non significant Shapiro-Wilk test does not mean that the data come from a normal distribution (real data never do!). It just means that the data are compatible with it (not enough evidence to reject). At the same time, they are compatible with an infinite number of non-normal distributions. All these issues have been extensively discussed on this site.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I do not like the shapiro test either, & recognize it also has it flaws. I do not use it in my own research either, but prefer things like tukey anscombe and qqplots.  That said, the shapiro test still exists, and is one option among many that can be used.  Thanks for your input

Comment: In practice, this is the wrong study design to say anything about a casual effect of coffee. An analysis treating this as unpaired observations is also just wrong.